# Trying to call a guid with JQuery to make delete button work

Tags: jquery

So far this is my code. I've been searching on the internet and trying all different things to get this button to work but it keeps failing. I'm pretty new at this so I'm just doing everything that I know. If anyone could take a look and give me some suggestions that would be much appreciated!

This is the guid code that I'm trying to execute.

```
<div id="guidtest">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecGUID) 
            </div>
```

this is a div I created to try to target the guid specifically

```
<div id="guidd">@RecGuid</div>
```

this is the javascript that is creating a popup window asking if they are sure they want to delete. What I'm trying to do is when they hit delete the second time to actually execute the delete.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#delete10').click(function () {
        var testing123 = $('#guidd').value;
        alert(testing123);
        $('#popup').attr('title', 'Confirm Delete').text('Are you sure you want to Delete?').dialog({
            buttons: {
                'Delete': function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url: '/Master/BuildingDelete' + testing123,
                        success: function(data){
                            testing123;
                        },
                        error: function (request, status, error) {
                            alert(request.responseText);
                            alert(textStatus);
                            alert(errorThrow);
                        }
                    });},
                'Cancel': function () { $(this).dialog('close') }},
            closeOnEscape: true, draggable:false, resizable:false, show:'fade', modal: true, position:'center'});
    });
    </script>
}
```

The delete code

```
 // Delete an existing Building Record (actually, set DeleteDt in it).
    public void DeleteBuilding(string strRecGUID, string strUser) {
        CertiFlow_IIEntities MyDB = new CertiFlow_IIEntities();
        this.IOOK = false;
        this.ErrMsg = "";
        try {
            string strSQL = "UPDATE tblInstitutionBuilding SET DeletedDt = getdate(), UpdateDt = getdate(), UpdateUser = {1} WHERE (RecGUID = {0})";
            MyDB.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(strSQL, strRecGUID, strUser);
            MyDB.SaveChanges();
            this.IOOK = true;
        } catch (Exception Ex) {
                this.ErrMsg = "An Error was Encountered while updating the Database for the Building: " + Ex.InnerException;
        }
        MyDB.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Code for Guids

```
<div class="entrylabel">Building Code</div>
    <div class = "displaydata">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BuildingCode)
    </div>
    <div class="entrylabel">Building Name</div>
    <div class="displaydata">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BuildingName)
    </div>
    <div class="entrylabel">Date Added</div>
    <div class = "displaydata">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateIn)
    </div>
    <div class="entrylabel">Date Updated</div>
    <div class = "displaydata">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UpdateDt)
    </div>
    <div class="entrylabel">Update User</div>
    <div class = "displaydata">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UpdateUser)
    </div>
    <div class="entrylabel"><br /></div>
    <div style="display:none"> 
        <div id="guidtest">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecGUID) 
            </div> 
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HGUID)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsNew)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UpdateUser)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UpdateDt)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateIn)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BuildingCode)
    </div>
```

Comment: where is this failing?  Does your BuildingDelete action get called?

Comment: Yes it seems like it does call it. I put a break at   
public void DeleteBuilding(string strRecGUID, string strUser) {

and when i click the second delete the break hits

Comment: please post the code of that action

Comment: do the alerts in the error functions fire?

Comment: currently no alerts are firing, the button just does nothing. This is the code that is being called and should be deleting this item.
posted code in main question

Comment: your success function doesn't do anything?

Comment: I'm trying to get the success function to fire the BuildingDelete code to delete the item